# Form builder easily integrable into a DXP (Uniform)?

Tags: forms, next.js

I am looking for a form builder that meets the following conditions :

- Easily integrable into a DXP (Uniform.dev <= this one)
- Preferably deployable on the edge with NextJS
- Conditional logic
- Multi-steps

Do you have some suggestions in mind ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

I tried looking for some options online but as I'm not the most technical person, it's hard for me to figure it out.